How to get linting score from ruff, similar to pylint score?
I would like to switch from pylint to ruff because of license compatibility issues. Currently I show our pylint score as a badge.
How can I get a score from ruff, similar to pylint score?
Your code has been rated at x/10 (previous run: y/10, +z)

If there is no direct score feature, maybe the score could be derived from some json output of ruff etc.?
Edit:
I opened a feature request for ruff:
https://github.com/astral-sh/ruff/issues/15125
